# Converting a pivot table to a flat table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, unpivot

I would like to transform a pivot table into a flat table, but in the following fashion: consider the simple example of this table:

[image]

As you can see, for each item - Address or Income -, we have a column for old values, and a column for new (updated values). I would like to convert the table to a "flat" table, looking like:

[image]

Is there an easy way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the result, you will need to UNPIVOT the data.  When you unpivot you convert the multiple columns into multiple rows, in doing so the datatypes of the data must be the same.

I would use CROSS APPLY to unpivot the columns in pairs:

```
select t.employee_id,
  t.employee_name,
  c.data,
  c.old,
  c.new
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  values 
  ('Address', Address_Old, Address_new),
  ('Income', cast(income_old as varchar(15)), cast(income_new as varchar(15)))
) c (data, old, new);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a69f/1).  As you can see this uses a `cast` on the `income` columns because I am guessing it is a different datatype from the `address`.  Since the final result will have these values in the same column the data must be of the same type.

This can also be written using CROSS APPLY with UNION ALL:

```
select t.employee_id,
  t.employee_name,
  c.data,
  c.old,
  c.new
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  select 'Address', Address_Old, Address_new union all
  select 'Income', cast(income_old as varchar(15)), cast(income_new as varchar(15))
) c (data, old, new)
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a69f/2)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But the first part of your query involves selecting from the "unpivoted" table. That table does not exist. The only one that exists is the pivot table.

Comment: @Mariam You would replace the `yourtable` with your pivot query.

Comment: Well, there is no pivot query per-say. The original table was created that way (pivot). Or maybe I am not quite following what you are saying.. sorry

Comment: @Mariam I guess I am missing something with your explanation.  I created a demo with your original table (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a69f/1) and using this query will give you the final result that you requested, the data in multiple rows.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for! But I get the following error when executing the query:  `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'.`

Comment: Any idea how to write an equivalent query in Oracle SQL? `cross apply` does not exist in Oracle. Thanks!

Comment: @Mariam My suggestion would be to post a new question with the tags for Oracle.

Comment: Yep! Thanks! That's what I did!!

Answer (score 1):

```
select employee_id,employee_name,data,old,new
from (
select employee_id,employee_name,adress_old as old,adress_new as new,'ADRESS' as data
from employe
union
select employee_id,employee_name,income_old,income_new,'INCOME'
from employe
 ) data
order by employee_id,data
```

see this fiddle demo :  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64344/7/0